# Spring Kafka Producer Test using Schema registry

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to use Spring Kafka to write tests for my producer application with its embedded Kafka server.

However my application also using confluent schema registry, I am wondering whether Spring Kafka provides some embedded server for schema registry?

Or are there any better way to do Spring Kafka tests with schema registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no schema registry provided by Spring Kafka; it is not Apache licensed; you can, however, use an external confluent registry with the embedded kafka broker.

Spring Cloud Stream does have a simple registry [docs here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#_schema_registry_server).

[It is in the process of being moved to its own project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1767).